# Connect To Web Service Using Android Device

Tags: android, web-services, c#-4.0, android-wifi

I'm Create a Web service Using C# in visual Studio.Using Android Emulator it's can call web method in the local host Environment,

So now i am try to Install my App in the Real Android device and Want to Call the Web service Using Wi-Fi(Or other way) In the local host Environment not in Hosting The Service in the Internet Web host.I also host the Service In My local host Using IIS.

Is this Can Do? Or i want to Change The Way I call the Web service In The local host , in this case I user to connect Web service Using Wi-Fi

```
          // send login request to the webservice

    String SOAP_ACTION_LOGIN = "http://tempuri.org/AuthenticateUser";
    String METHOD_NAME_LOGIN = "AuthenticateUser";
    String URL_LOGIN = "http://10.0.2.2:100/Service1.asmx?op=AuthenticateUser";
```

Comment: Yes, you need to change local host to the pc's local ip

Comment: How It can be done , Is There any S/W or In the Visual Studio or TCP/IP Configuration

Comment: Nah, go to command prompt, type `ipconfig` it will give you your pc's ip, replace it with local host and its done

Comment: nopes, its for Emulator, there should be an ip like 192.168.1.200

Comment: how can i find the local host Ip, can please Elaborate this Little bit

Comment: have you read my 2nd comment ?

Comment: If i use Wireless Router to do this how it can be done, mean i connect to the Router first by using Android and Call the Method in the localhost

Comment: that is what i am telling you, first get your local pc's ip, and in your code, write that ip instead of 'localhost', when you run this app in device your device should be connected via WiFi

Comment: Can u send me the steps if i give my E-mail and this is the IP 10.0.2.2